# trying to have a login form in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
         login.php:

               <?php
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
          mysql_select_db("koro",$con);

           $result= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE                    
          UNAME='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Uneym'])."'"; 
           echo $result; 
             $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
                       echo $num;
                  for($i=1;$i<=$num; $i++){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
           $user=$row['UNAME']; 
           $pass=$row['PW'];
           }
           }


           if($username == $user && $password ==$pass)
       {
            echo "<script>alert('Login Successful!')</script>";
           }
            else if($password!= $pass ||$username != $user )
             {
            echo("Please Enter Correct Username and Password ...");
           ?>
```

loginform.php:

```
      <html>
   <form action="login.php" method="post">

         Username:<input type="text" name="Uneym" value="" /><br/>
               Password:<input type="password" name="Pass" value="" /><br/>

         <br/>
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="" />

           </form>
</head>
          <body>
       </body>
          </html>
```

-Is there a simpler code for a beginner like me?:)

Comment: You should explain what's wrong with our current code (apart from indentation) and how it relates to phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think he misread it phpadmin, since it is a login script, and didn't know about the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't too complex - it can't be made much simpler at all if it is to do the job.
But, you shouldn't be storing passwords in your database unencrypted like that. Take a look at this article on [hashing passwords in mysql](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2006/08/storing-passwords-in-mysql.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it as a teaching exercise, no there is no easier way to do it, and make sure it works (although you could do it all as one page, so that if it has an error you can try again).

Realistically, it is too simple. You should hash the passwords, use a salt, enforce good passwords, have a maximum login attempts count, and store any user info in a session. But all that can come later....

Answer (score 1):

1) The first bug is that you never submit the query to the DBMS - your code should look something like:

```
$dbh=mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db(...,$dbh); // note see below
$result=mysql_query(....$dbh);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  ...
}
```

2) You've got 2 loops (a for loop and a while loop) around the code which retrieves rows from the query - there should only be one. So if your query returns 3 rows, you actually loop around 9 times:

1) for loop iteration 1
2) while loop iteration 1 fetches row 1, writes results
3) while loop iteration 2 fetches row 2, writes results
4) while loop iteration 3 fetches row 3, writes results
5) while loop fails on subsequent iteration
6) for loop iteration 2
7) while loop fails on subsequent iteration
8) for loop iteration 3
9) while loop fails on subsequent iteration

3) You assign the values returned by the mysql_fetch_assoc to scalar variables (i.e. you overwrite te result each time - so $user and $pass always contain the values from the last row returned.

4) Its good practice to establish early exit criteria within a loop - in addition to avoiding redundant execution, this would also solve the 3rd bug described above, e.g.

```
$valid=false;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
       if (($username==$row['UNAME']) && ($password==$row['PW'])) {
           $valid=true;
           break;
       }
}
if ($valid) {....
```

4) The next problem is why are you checking if the username matches $username when you've previously said it should be the same as $_POST['Uneym'].

5) The next problem is that you seem to have written this code with register_globals enabled.

6) The next problem is that you are needlessly fetching data from the database - just add a filter on the password then you'll only get 1 or zero rows (and you don't even need to iterate through the result set):

```
 $user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Uneym'], $dbh);
 $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'], $dbh);
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UNAME='$user' AND PW='$pass'",$dbh);
 $valid=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and still there's more:

7)
    if($username == $user && $password ==$pass)
       {
            echo "alert('Login Successful!')";
           }
            else if($password!= $pass ||$username != $user )
             {
            echo("Please Enter Correct Username and Password ...");
           ?>

This will not parse - there's an unmatched '{' after the else

8) The condition in the else statement is redundant - the code will only ever go into the else clause if it fails the if clause, and by definition,

($username == $user && $password ==$pass) === ! ($password!= $pass ||$username != $user )

9) using mysql_select_db() can make life very complicated if you are working with multiple mysql databases - in general its a better idea to exlpicitly state which database a table resides in with the DML statement.

C.